# Creating new vector that represents the count

Tags: r, count

I want to create a vector of counts in the following way:

say my vector is

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,2)
```

which represents a categorical variable.
I want a second vector of the form

```
x1 <- c(4,4,4,4,1)
```

which represents the count at each level. e.g. 4 occurrences of level 1, and 1 occurrence of level 2.

I have tried

```
r <- range(x) ; table(factor(x, levels = r[1]:r[2])) 
tabulate(factor(x, levels = min(x):max(x)))
table(x)
```

Comment: if your vector is sorted and consequetive as you have shown, you could use `table(x)[x]`

Comment: I suppose that would work as well since the table is sorted, as long as your consecutive -- for example, `x <- c(1,1,3)` will have an index out of range

Comment: thanks this will work! will just need to sort first.

Comment: I don't think the sorting is necessary, I had forgotten the tables sort by column index. You may want to double check though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This uses `ave` to group by each value. This would likely be better if your vector is definitely an `integer` type.

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,2)

ave(x, x,  FUN = length)
[1] 4 4 4 4 1
```

Equivalents in `data.table` and `dplyr`:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(x)[, n:= .N, by = 'x'][]

   x n
1: 1 4
2: 1 4
3: 1 4
4: 1 4
5: 2 1

library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
tibble::enframe(x, name = NULL)%>%
  add_count(value)

##or

x%>%
  tibble::enframe(name = NULL)%>%
  group_by(value)%>%
  mutate(n = n())%>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  value     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     1     4
2     1     4
3     1     4
4     1     4
5     2     1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do it like this:

```
x = c(1,1,1,1,2)
x1 = as.vector(table(x)[x])
```

You obtain the vector you wanted:

> [1] 4 4 4 4 1

Comment: I think you don't need `r <- range(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tabulate` or `table` along with `rep`

```
x1 <- tabulate(x)
rep(x1,x1)
#[1] 4 4 4 4 1

x1 <- table(x)
as.integer(rep(x1, x1))
#[1] 4 4 4 4 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fct_count` from `forcats` which has a `sort` argument too:

```
x <- as.factor(x)
forcats::fct_count(x)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  f         n
  <fct> <int>
1 1         4
2 2         1
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `tapply` from `base R`.

```
v1 <- tapply(x, x, FUN = length)
rep(as.integer(v1), v1)
#[1] 4 4 4 4 1
```

NB: It is a dupe